# Orko's magical power and ability when fulfilling his full potential

Tags: magic, he-man, masters-of-the-universe

*Orko* from "He-Man and The Masters of The Universe" is often portrayed as a clumsy failing sorcerer, but it is hinted that when he unleashes his full potential he is a very powerful sorcerer.

In "Masters of The Universe: Revelation" (2021, Netflix), when *Orko* is at his full strength, he manages to defeat *Evil-Lyn*, who was augmented with the power of the universe obtained from the sword, and had the power of Castle Grayskull as she was the reigning sorceress. He also defeats *Scare-Glow* rather easily.

The question is: when *Orko* is at his full strength and lives up to his full potential, is he the most powerful sorcerer/mage/wizard in the universe? (Potential contenders: The Sorceress *Tila-Naa*, *Skeletor*, *Evil-Lyn*, *Hordak* and *Shadow-Weaver*)

Comment: Most powerful is a mathematically hard claim to prove for anyone.